# What is the purpose of sudo -i

Tags: sudo

`man sudo` says `sudo -i` has to do with login shell at least that's how I understood it.

But when I typed it I landed on the root directory. Does that mean I became root and no need to type `sudo`?

Comment: Indeed, it made you `root`!

Comment: This very first line: "                Run the shell specified by the target user's password data‐
                base entry as a login shell." - as a non-english speaker I'm having a hard time understanding it. I only want to know whether it means (interactive screen) or elevated user rights. The manual says -c: is that supposed to be typed or not? Perhaps the best answer for me would be for someone to give out some random example on how to perform this command.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/what-are-the-differences-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i-sudo-su) is pretty detailed.

Comment: `sudo -i` is basically the same thing as logging in as root, except you type your own password instead of that of the `root` user. You can add `-u user` to the command, i.e. `sudo -i -u user` to make it behave as if user `user` logged in.